# detect calendar change on input type html

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I have used a calendar from so called [DateTimePicker.js](http://technoscatter.blogspot.com/2011/03/javascript-calendar-datetime-picker.html) and also used it on my html e.g:

```
<input id="startDate" name="startDate" id="startDate" type="text" size="20" value="">
    <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('startDate','ddMMyyyy','arrow')">
        <img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"/></a>
</input>
```

The question is, how can i detect any changes on calendar since I tried to test with the following jQuery but apparently it didn't work:

```
   <input id="startDate" name="startDate" id = "startDate" type="text" size="20"  value="">
   <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#startDate").bind('change', function(e) {
            alert('changing date!');
        });
    });
   </script>
   <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('startDate','ddMMyyyy','arrow')">
      <img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"/>
   </a>
   </input>
```

Comment: Please link to that `DateTimePicker.js` file or to the website of that library/plugin. How you name your files is irrelevant. Also, create the "pick date"-link properly if you have jQuery available (i.e. do not use inline event handlers)

Comment: @Bergi:sorry, i don't get you. How can i link to the file or its website?

Comment: We need to know the scripts content (not its name). So please post it, or link to it (and if it's a common, well-documented lib, you may as well link to the project website). See [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for creating links

Comment: @Bergi: Please have a look at my edited question above.

Comment: Thanks. You rather would not use that script, it combines a bunch of bad practices. Also, it does not seem to offer a `change` callback as required by you, and I guess hacking that feature in would be a pain.

Comment: @Bergi: Any alternative solutions, perhaps?

Comment: Found this list by googling: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/08/jquery-datepicker.html. Haven't used one myself for now, but the one that is shipped with jQueryUI seems to have good docs and support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output(viewsource) is something like

```
<input id="startDate" readonly="readonly" name="startDate" id = "startDate" type="text" size="20"  value="">
```

Which contains **readonly="readonly"** which makes your input readonly due to which change event is not raised.

Solution:

1) On Page load, create a variable and store the startDate textbox value in it, use settimeout function to periodically check the textbox value with the variable and call a function to do your task on change of textbox.

2) Once document is ready and dom is loaded, write code to set the textbox readonly property to FALSE and set disabled=true. and then bind and use the change event.

```
$(document).ready(){function(){  your code here });
```

3) Use [jquery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger), its easy to use and implement.